# Code to aggregate objects has different results between browsers

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with random row and size attributes:

```
var array = [{ row:1, size: 2 },{ row:1, size 1 },{ row:1, size: 2 },{ row:2, size:1 },{ row:2, size:1 },{ row:2, size:2 }]
```

Note: *size: 1 = 1 row, size: 2 = 2 rows*

I need to loop through each object and process both the row count and size count to come up with a total row amount.  So, I've written this:

```
// Attempt to save larges size values for each row
    var rowHeightsObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(!rowHeightsObj[array[i].row]) { rowHeightsObj[array[i].row] = 0 };
      if( rowHeightsObj[array[i].row] < array[i].size ) {  rowHeightsObj[array[i].row] = array[i].size };
    };

// If A previous Row is sized 2 than make that previous row 0
    for (var key in rowHeightsObj) {
      if (rowHeightsObj[key - 1] == 2) {
          rowHeightsObj[key] = 0
      };
    };

// Collect the total row height 
    rowHeightsTotal = 0;
    for (var key in rowHeightsObj) {
      rowHeightsTotal = rowHeightsTotal + rowHeightsObj[key] 
    };
```

But I'm getting a different rowHeightsTotal on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.  Why is this?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle. The chances of "core" JavaScript behaving differently across [all modern] browsers is .. about 0. As such, I would *first* suspect that the browsers are using different cached versions or somehow have different data. A jsfiddle will allow either reproduction or isolation of the issue. Also, JSON *is text*, so no text -> no JSON.

Comment: From your example `array`, what are you expecting to end up with?